# Tables alignment in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have 3 tables in my report, lay out like this: A next to B above C, as follows:

```
A B

C
```

Now, when I run the report builder, table C gets a lot bigger because it's filled with data, and this pushes table B a lot to the right, and as a result, table B is too far away from table A.

Putting A and B into the same rectangle does not seem to modify the behavior.

Is there a way to keep tables A and B closer together?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I touched up the question a bit.

Comment: Put A & B in the same left-justified cell in an outer Tablix, and C in a single cell in the row below.

Comment: How to put different tables into a tablix?